Distribution of product and sum of beta random variables
I have a set of probabilities that I am modelling as (independent) $p_{A,i} \sim Beta(\alpha_{A,i},\beta_{A,i})$ and $p_{B,i} \sim Beta(\alpha_{B,i},\beta_{B,i})$. I am calculating the following product:
$$Y = \sum_{i=1}^N p_{A,i}^{n_{A}}(1-p_{B,i})^{n_{B}} + p_{B,i}^{n_{B}}(1-p_{A,i})^{n_{A}},$$
with $n_{A}$ and $n_{B}$ integers. I want to infer (approximate) the cumulative distribution of $Y$. Because of $Y$ is skewed with support for values $\gt 1$ I was thinking in fitting a Beta-Prime (or log-normal) density distribution to $Y$. Would this be correct? Could you please give me some insights on the true distribution of $Y$ or on a better approximation for it?
PD. Sorry if something similar to this question has been asked before.

Although you refer to "$n_{Ai}$" and "$n_{Bi},$" these do not appear anywhere in your expression for $Y.$  Please clarify.

I modified your definition of $Y$ as my guess to the issue that @whuber mentions.  Please change back if I've misinterpreted your intent.  (Also, are you a C/Java programmer or is there some subject matter reason why you start your index at 0?)

Thank you for your suggestions. I have fixed the indexes in the expressions, the numbers $n_A$ and $n_B$ are constant, and only the probabilities depend on $i$.

For a given N, Y is limited to a finite interval, its support is neither the real line nor the positive half line. Naturally if almost all the density is far from the upper limit some distribution on the positive half line might work okay as an approximation

You're right Glen, thanks for bringing this up.

Just a baby step:  Consider $N=1$.  We can write a function that finds the P-value (again, in Mathematica).
pValue[z_, nA_, nB_, αA_, βA_, αB_, βB_] :=
   If[z < 0, 1, 
    If[z > 1, 0, 
      NProbability[(pA^nA  (1 - pB)^nB + (1 - pA)^nA  pB^nB) > z,
        {pA \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[αA, βA], 
         pB \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[αB, βB]}]]]

Plot[pValue[y, 3, 7, 2, 3, 5, 1], {y, -0.1, 1.1}, AxesLabel -> {"y", "Pr(Y >= y)"}]


But it is probably simpler and quicker to estimate the P-value using a Monte Carlo approach:
(* Number of simulations *)
nSimulations = 100000;

(* Set beta distribution parameters *)
SeedRandom[12345];
α = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{1, 10}], {n, 2}];
β = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{1, 10}], {n, 2}];

(* Set counts *)
nA = 7;
nB = 5;

(* Generate random samples of y *)
n = 4;  (* This is N in the question *)
pA = ConstantArray[0, {nSimulations, n}];
pB = ConstantArray[0, {nSimulations, n}];
Do[
 pA[[All, i]] = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[α[[i, 1]], β[[i, 1]]], 
   nSimulations];
 pB[[All, i]] = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[α[[i, 2]], β[[i, 2]]], 
   nSimulations],
 {i, 1, n}]
y = Total[#] & /@ (pA^nA  (1 - pB)^nB + (1 - pA)^nA  pB^nB);
Histogram[y, "FreedmanDiaconis", "SF", Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"y", "P-Value"}]


(* Estimate P-value for y = 0.15 *)
pValue = Length[Select[y, # >= 0.15 &]]/nSimulations // N
(* 0.04033 *)


Thank you Jim. This is really helpful.

The Monte Carlo approach can, of course, be easily programmed in R, too.  I can get an explicit formula for the pdf and cdf but so far only when $n_A$ and $n_B$ are just 1 or 2 and all of the beta distribution parameters are integers and $N=1$.

This is just an extended comment.  First, I don't think you'll be able to find an explicit symbolic formula for the pdf of $Y$.  But if at some point you have a potential family of distributions and want to match moments (given the values of the parameters), here is one way to obtain the exact mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis of $Y$.
All moments will be sums of expectations of terms of the form
$$p_{A_i}^{k_A} \times p_{B_i}^{k_B}$$
Using Mathematica one can define a replacement rule that covers all possible expectations:
(* Rules for expectations of pA[i]^kA * pB[i]^kB *)
expectationRules = {
   pA[i_]^kA_ pB[i_]^kB_ -> (Gamma[kA + αA[i]] Gamma[kB + αB[i]] Gamma[βA[i]] Gamma[βB[i]])/
     (Beta[αA[i], βA[i]] Beta[αB[i], βB[i]] Gamma[kA + αA[i] + βA[i]] Gamma[kB + αB[i] + βB[i]]),
   pA[i_]^kA_ pB[i_] -> (Gamma[kA + αA[i]] Gamma[1 + αB[i]] Gamma[βA[i]]  Gamma[βB[i]])/
     (Beta[αA[i], βA[i]] Beta[αB[i], βB[i]] Gamma[kA + αA[i] + βA[i]] Gamma[1 + αB[i] + βB[i]]),
   pA[i_]  pB[i_]^kB_ -> (Gamma[1 + αA[i]] Gamma[kB + αB[i]] Gamma[βA[i]]  Gamma[βB[i]])/
     (Beta[αA[i], βA[i]] Beta[αB[i], βB[i]] Gamma[1 + αA[i] + βA[i]]  Gamma[kB + αB[i] + βB[i]]),
   pA[i_]  pB[i_] -> (Gamma[1 + αA[i]] Gamma[1 + αB[i]] Gamma[βA[i]]  Gamma[βB[i]])/
     (Beta[αA[i], βA[i]] Beta[αB[i], βB[i]] Gamma[1 + αA[i] + βA[i]] Gamma[1 + αB[i] + βB[i]]),
   pA[i_]^kA_ -> (Gamma[kA + αA[i]] Gamma[βA[i]])/(Beta[αA[i], βA[i]] Gamma[kA + αA[i] + βA[i]]),
   pB[i_]^kB_ -> (Gamma[kB + αB[i]] Gamma[βB[i]])/(Beta[αB[i], βB[i]] Gamma[kB + αB[i] + βB[i]]),
   pA[i_] -> αA[i]/(αA[i] + βA[i]),
   pB[i_] -> αB[i]/(αB[i] + βB[i])};

Now for a specific set of parameters we can find the mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis:
(* Set parameters *)
counts = {nA -> 3, nB -> 2};
parms = {αA[1] -> 1, βA[1] -> 4, αB[1] -> 3, βB[1] -> 2};

(* Define y *)
y = Sum[pA[i]^nA (1 - pB[i])^nB + pB[i]^nB (1 - pA[i])^nA, {i, 1, Length[parms]/4}] // Expand;

(* Find mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis *)
mean = ((y /. counts // Expand) /. expectationRules) /. parms // N
(* 0.234286 *)
variance = (((y - mean)^2 /. counts // Expand) /. expectationRules) /. parms // N
(* 0.0315728 *)
skewness = ((((y - mean)^3 /. counts // Expand) /. expectationRules) /. parms)/variance^(3/2) // N
(* 1.08566 *)
kurtosis = ((((y - mean)^4 /. counts // Expand) /. expectationRules) /. parms)/variance^2 // N
(* 3.6445 *)


Than you for your comment JimB. I was thinking on approximating the distribution of $Y$ by a beta-prime (or log-normal) distribution with the same mean and variance, do you think this would lead to good estimations of p-values?

I'm not understanding how P-values got into the picture.  But are there values of $nA$ and $nB$ of interest?  Small integer values?  Large values?  Any particular values for the beta distribution parameters?

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I need the cumulative distribution of Y (to calculate p-values for an unmentioned hypothesis test). There is no constriction on the values $n_A$ or $n_B$.

If it is just about getting a P-value for a specified set of beta distribution parameters and fixed values of $n_A$ and $n_B$, you might just want to do a Monte Carlo approach.
